# Return First Item from Multiple Sources with Where() foreach return

Tags: c#, linq

I found an interesting code snippet that uses a Where() and foreach in ways not intended. However, their usage seems to be a very interesting solution that reduces the lines of code significantly.

```
// a, b, c are IEnumerable<string> of any data source and could be expensive to iterate
string GetFirstString(){

    foreach( var str in a.Where(...) )
        return str;

    foreach( var str in b.Where(...) )
        return str;

    foreach( var str in c.Where(...) )
        return str;

    return "";

}
```

Is there a better way to do this that is just as short, but does not "abuse" the Where and foreach?

UPDATE:

This could have a bug if any list contains a null entry and the Where predicate allows the null entry through, then it will return null. (It should be expected for GetFirstString to skip over null values in most cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string GetFirstString(){
    return a.FirstOrDefault(...) 
        ?? b.FirstOrDefault(...) 
        ?? c.FirstOrDefault(...)
        ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.

Comment: Note: This does change the logic slightly - if any list contains a null value (and the predicate allows a null value), then it will return "" whereas the original foreach solution would return null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Concat` to join everything to a single sequence, then select the `First`.

```
var list = a.Where(...)
           .Concat(b.Where(...))
           .Concat(c.Where(..))
           .Take(1)
           .ToList();//Make sure we execute the query only once.

if(list.Count > 0)
    return list[0];

return "";
```

Note: You could think that `Take(1)`, `ToList` and returning the first element from the list seems redundant and you could change it to `FirstOrDefault`. But that changes the semantics of the code. Problem is that when your filtered sequence contains `null`, then `FirstOrDefault() ?? ""` will return empty string, but OP's original code will return `null` instead.

Comment: Also, if the expressions in each Where() are the same (OP didn't mention, but it's a good bet they are) I would just do all the concats first: `a.Concat(b).Concat(c).Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`, checking the value for null before returning of course, and returning `""` if it is.

Comment: This seems a little overly complex at the end.

Comment: from Take(1) and below, it could be replaced with FirstOrDefault() ?? "";

Comment: @RickLove You could replace it with `FirstOrDefault() ?? ""` but if list contains `null` value, instead of returning null you'll be returning "". If that is fine, then you can.

Comment: @Sriram - Yes, I see your point. That is true for the other answers also that rely on FirstOrDefault().

Comment: That's the reason why I chosen not to use `FirstOrDefault` :).

Answer (score 1):

```
string GetFirstString(){

    var str = "";

    if( str == null )
        str = b.FirstOrDefault(...);

    if( str == null )
        str = b.FirstOrDefault(...);

    if( str == null )
        str = c.FirstOrDefault(...);

    return str;
}
```

This seems kind of ugly to me because it introduces a variable and changes the whole structure of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirstOrDefault() instead of First()

```
string GetFirstString(){

        if (a.Any(...))
           return a.FirstOrDefault(...);

        if (b.Any(...))
           return b.FirstOrDefault(...);

        if (c.Any(...))
           return c.FirstOrDefault(...);

        return "";

    }
```

Comment: This iterates each data source twice

Comment: @RickLove no it doesnt, it depends on the datasource

Comment: It doesn't iterate the whole sequence, but it would still be better to just pass the `Any(...)` predicate to the `FirstOrDefault(...)` method instead (going on to the next sequence if `FirstOrDefault(...)` returns null, of course).

Comment: @DavidPilkington Ok, well it could, and that should be avoided for potentially expensive calls. Though, this does make me wonder how different data sources handle Any()...

Comment: This is wrong. Any will check for the predicate match, but First picks up first element in the list irrespective of the predicate.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Union` extension method

```
string GetFirstString()
{
    return a.Where(...)
        .Union(b.Where(...))
        .Union(c.Where(...)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Union would compare all items to check for distinct values. This would be very expensive. Concat() would be ok.